# JazzyViewPager java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, classnotfoundexception

I replaced the standard viewpager with JazzyView pager (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager) by importing the project and adding a dependency and then editing the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.JazzyViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.JazzyViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

But I get an error:

The following classes could not be found: - com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.JazzyViewPager

When I remove the project and add the jar to the build path then I get this error:

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.JazzyViewPager
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.R$styleable
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(    at
>   com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.JazzyViewPager.(JazzyViewPager.java:67)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)

I know how to add library dependencies so I don't think I did something wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

How did you add the project reference? Did you go to Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add? This is not the same as Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Add. You should use the first way.

The second problem is normal because JazzyView is a Android Library and when you export it as jar, the Resources will be missing. You will never be able to do it that way.

Comment: Yes, I did, but when I do, I get this error:

`C:\Users\SUYASH 1\Downloads\Compressed\SlidingMenu-master\SlidingMenu-master\library\res\values\attrs.xml:39: error: Attribute "fadeEnabled" has already been defined` and `R cannot be resolved to a variable` error in all Java class files.

Comment: That means the fadeEnabled attribute is duplicated. 
Did you copy the attrs.xml file from the library project to your project while you were trying to setup with the Jar file?

Comment: Nope I did not copy that file

Comment: If you do a file search for "fadeEnabled" in all files, in what files do you see it?

Comment: So, you have the fadeEnabled attribute defined in both "JazzyViewPager" and "SlidingMenu" attrs.xml files. 
You are importing both libraries in your project and that makes a conflict. You can just delete one of them. Make that for any other duplicated attributes. And don't forget to clean&build the projects. 
That should do it.

Comment: I did that, but another error: `08-27 20:47:31.710: E/AndroidRuntime(14360): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Required method instantiateItem was not overridden`

Here's my instantiateItem function code: `@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
JazzyViewPager pager = (JazzyViewPager) container;
pager.setTransitionEffect(TransitionEffect.Tablet);
View page = inflater.inflate(pages[position], null);
pager.addView(page);
Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
pager.setObjectForPosition(obj, position);
return obj' }`

Comment: You are overriding "public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) "
instead you should be overriding "public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position)"

Notice that the correct one receives a viewGroup instead of the View.

Comment: I get a 08-27 21:03:28.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20287): java.lang.NullPointerException. Here's my full Adapter code: http://pastebin.com/hGzK00PX

Comment: In what line is the NullPointerException, can you put here the full stack?

Comment: You are forgetting to initialize "private JazzyViewPager pager;"
And you shouldn't be calling "super.instantiateItem(container, pages[position])"

Comment: Check how the guys from JazzyViewPager create the adapter at https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager/blob/master/lib/src/com/jfeinstein/jazzyviewpager/MainActivity.java on line 55

Answer (score 0):

As per the link [android dependencies](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects), the `R` class is no more packaged in the jar ouptut of the library projects. Also see the same link for adding android libraries as a dependencies for your project.

Answer (score 0):

You must need to see your set content `setContentView(R.layout.buttonslideshowlayout)` where u placed a control xml name

```
<com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager..JazzyViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/jazzy_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/h1" />
```

here change `com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager` with your project name and its done i also did this for my own project problem